# How to get image size from Next.js's API route (hosted on Vercel)?

Tags: node.js, next.js, path, vercel

I need to get image dimensions from an API route of Next.js. Locally (both with `npm run dev` and `npm run build && npm start`) this (pseudo) code works:

```
import path from 'path';
import imageSize from 'image-size';

export default async function ApiEndpoint(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { width, height } = imageSize(path.join('./public', photo));
  ... other things
}
```

On Vercel however it does not and I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/public/stories/tatiana.jpeg'
```

I've tried variations of the path (such as 'public', './public', '/public' or omitting "public") to no avail. Adding `process.cwd()` to the path leads to the same error.

Is there a recommended way how to read a file dynamically (not with import) in the API route of Next.js hosted on Vercel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the image added to the `public` folder dynamically at runtime, or is it already present at build time?

Comment: Present at build time, but I need to read it dynamically in client ("load more" button in pagination).

Comment: Where does `photo` come from in the API route? Is it a dynamic value?

Comment: From a JSON file in `./db` folder, so it is a static value.

`[
 { post_title: 'Post 1', photo: '/blog/image-1.jpg' },
 { post_title: 'Post 2', photo: '/blog/image-2.jpg' },
]
`

Images are in `/public/blog` folder.